# why etcd.conf is deprecated after etcd 2.x?

Tags: configuration, etcd

When I tried to start etcd based on the version 2.1, I found there is no options for `-config` and `-f` any more. I am confused why starting etcd by `etcd.conf` is deprecated after 2.x.